# WTP(eclipse3.7) can not start tomcat6 in a debug mode under Windows7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

WTP(eclipse3.7) can not start tomcat6 in  a debug mode  under Windows7，Here is the error log：

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2011-11-23 22:26:33.001
!MESSAGE Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Comment: Error message suggests that you are using **Resin** and not Tomcat.  Anything else in the logs?

Comment: This is the eclipse error log.This is the complete contents of the log

Answer (score 0):

As there is not enough information to find the root cause, here are some things which you can try:
- Is Tomcat starting from outside i.e. not from eclipse but by launching stratup.bat file of Tomcat? Make sure your tomcat is working properly.
- did you configure resource(your project) while configuring the WTP.
- As you have very specifically said that it's not working in debug mode, is it working on normal mode? If yes, then you have to copy the start configuration to debug configuration.

Do share if you have some more information on this.